# Как сделать один запрос для всех связанных объектов?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Модель_1(models.Model): 
    поле = models.IntegerField()


class Модель_2(models.Model):
    модель_1 = models.ForeignKey(Модель_1, related_name="модели_1")


модели_1 = Модель_1.objects.filter(поле="значение")
```

Вот выбрал я модели, либо часть моделей.

Как теперь отдельно, одним запросом - важно именно одним запросом и без использования prefetch_related, выбрать все Модели2, которые связаны с уже выбранными Моделями1?

Просто есть мысль попробовать пользоваться values(), для выборки. А там нельзя загружать связанные таблицы сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ids = модели_1.values_list('id', flat=True)

#или, если queryset уже выбран из базы
ids = [o.id for o in модели_1]

Модель_2.objects.filter(модель_1_id__in=ids)
```